# Will this pepper seedling survive being spilled from it's pot?

Tags: seedlings, bell-peppers

I started growing some sweet peppers plants about 2 weeks ago.  Yesterday I was moving them out of the window to get them away from the cold and I accidentally dropped one of the containers and spilled the dirt everywhere (the seedling hadn't come through the dirt yet).  I managed to find the seedling in the mess. The root seemed intact, so I pulled off the seed coat which was stuck and put it back in the dirt.  The cotyledon leaves are out, but they're not pointing straight up, they're kinda flopped down towards the dirt.  Any chance this thing is going to survive?

Here's a visual

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a chance; I've had worse happen to things I've started which went on to flourish, though not bell-peppers specifically.

Comment: It's actually perking up, looks like it's taking off!

Comment: You'd be surprised how tough peppers are. You don't need to pull the "helmets" off them, it's actually better that you leave it alone and let it work its own way out, lest you end up breaking the cotys. Sometimes they won't work their entire way out of the seed casting but will still grow just fine. Eventually the cotys will fall off anyway.